# Express.js Resets Connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, bluebird

I have a really, really simple Express.js app, but when it experiences a high load of POST requests, it resets the connection for a few of them.

Here is the app code:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var BPromise = require("bluebird");

var app = express();

function my_route(req, res) {
    var array = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        array.push(Math.random());
    array.sort();

    BPromise.resolve(true)
    .then(function(){
        res.send(true);
    });
}

app.use("/", my_route);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(1390, function() {
    console.log("Launched server.");
});
```

I have this code running in cluster mode (via PM2) behind a very run-of-the-mill NGINX reverse proxy. 
To test the configuration, I am hammering it with enough POSTs to fill CPU utilization from a separate server running apache bench:

```
ab -n 600000 -p body.json -c 32 [my public ip address]
```

Out of the 600000 requests sent, maybe 1-4 come back with non-2xx responses.  The Nginx logs have the following error:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

The error that Nginx is providing tells me that the problem lies not with Nginx, but with Express, Node, or Bluebird.  I am running Node v8.9.4, Express v4.16.2, Bluebird v3.5.1, and Nginx v1.13.8.

Can anyone help me figure out why Express is hanging up the phone?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's probably the TCP stack for your OS at the lowest level saying that it has queued up the most connections it is configured for and will immediately reject any others beyond that limit.  Express can contribute to this issue if it is slow at servicing an incoming connection because it's overly busy handling other connections.  If you have any synchronous I/O or CPU intensive operations that could contribute.

Comment: Why would this happen if I am only issuing 32 outstanding POSTs at a time?  I'm running this on an 8-core machine.  Is the OS queue really not able to handle the 24 waiting POSTs?

Comment: I wonder if it is affecting things that you never read the data from the stream that comes with the POST request.  I wonder if that's hanging out until it eventually times out?

Comment: Also worth reading about the `backlog` parameter here: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this.  I tried increasing `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` to 65536, `net.core.somaxconn` to 1024, and backlog in my `listen()` call to 65536, but the problem still persisted.  I think this may be a problem with Express or even Node, since the problem disappears when I use Node v7.  I am going to submit it as an issue to Express, see if anyone there can reproduce, and report back.

Comment: Before you submit an issue on Express, you should try to reproduce with a generic http server using the `http` module.  If it reproduces there, then it isn't Express' fault.  If it doesn't reproduce there, then you have a smoking gun pointing at Express.  I rather doubt Express has anything to do with this personally unless it's the failure to read the stream that I mentioned earlier.   If it has anything to do with node.js, then it's probably either the TCP or HTTP modules that are at fault.

Comment: Another idea is to get the underlying TCP socket from each incoming request and listen for the `close` and `end` events and see if they are occurring much later than you expect, indicating that sockets aren't getting closed when you expect them to be.

Comment: Another idea is to try to reproduce with only a GET request which would eliminate the reading of the stream.